# How to export Geometry Nodes animation with UV map

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes, export

I made an animation of a flower growing and blooming, that I want to export as an alembic file and render in 3D Studio Max.

The problem is that I can't seem to export the UV map with the animation.
The UV map is stored in a generic attribute and those aren't recognized as UV maps during export. From what I find online (a source from june 2022), the way to export the UV map is to apply the *Geometry Nodes* modifier and use the *convert attribute* action to convert the generic attribute to a UV map, this way it is recognized and thus get's exported.

My problem is that this is not an option for an animation, because the moment I apply the modifier everything is baked in.

I was wondering if there has been an update that makes exporting of *Geometry Nodes* animations with UV maps possible, or if there is some kind of workaround with an addon or something.